# How do I format a DateTime to be displayed as simply the time of day in a Razor-generated view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, razor

I am supplying a full DateTime located at model.StartDate in the following code:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StartDate.ToString("hh:mm tt"),
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hu-HU"));
```

My goal is to take the full DateTime

```
8/30/2012 11:33:48 AM
```

and display only

```
11:33:48 AM
```

however, I get the following error:

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

Why is this error happening?

---

Note:  I referenced this documentation to format my .ToString for my DateTime: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a DataAnnotation on your model class.  Something like this -> [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)].

Comment: For reference, the exact formatting I needed was: `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0: h:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`

Answer (score 1):

Create a new property on your model that returns the formatted date.

```
public class MyModel
{
    // Other fields including your current StartDate

    public class StartDateFormatted
    {
        get 
        { 
            return StartDate.ToString("hh:mm tt"), 
               CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hu-HU"));
        }
    }
}
```

Then use that property in your Razor markup

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StartDateFormatted);
```