# formatting DateTime error "No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In MVC Razor view, I am trying to format a DateTime field to display time only. Using below code I am getting error "No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments"

```
<td>@(Html.DisplayFor(m=>row.LastUpdatedDate).ToString("HH:mm:ss"))</td>
```

Any help please what is causing this error and how to fix it ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I format a DateTime to be displayed as simply the time of day in a Razor-generated view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201986/how-do-i-format-a-datetime-to-be-displayed-as-simply-the-time-of-day-in-a-razor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) returns `MvcHtmlString` which does not have `ToString` with one argument thus causing error you see.

You may not even need `DisplayFor` if you need just to show the date time value:

```
<td>@row.LastUpdatedDate.ToString("HH:mm:ss")</td>
```

Comment: Thanks Alexei Levenkov, I really appreciate your reply. You are right, it do not have a .ToString method. I was considering .ToString is available everywhere. Can't understand actually beofore I was able to do @(Html.DisplayFor(m=>row.CurrencyFrom).ToString().ToLower())

Comment: @Toubi - every object have `ToString()` (no arguments) - so you can call it on any object (often giving you results you don't expect like `Array[]`), but only specific classes (like `DateTime.TosString(string format)`) have additional versions of `ToString` with more arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Try use a [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute on the property in the model.

```
...
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm:ss}")]
public DateTime LastUpdatedDate{get; set;}
...
```